# Proxy not working for sending requests from one port to another

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, proxy, mern

I'm trying to build a simple web app using the MERN stack while following a course.

My backend runs on port 5000 while react runs on port 3000. When I want to make a request with the backend API, it sends it to port 3000 instead of 5000. I keep on getting this error message:

> xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3000/api/users 400 (Bad Request)

I included `"proxy" : "http://localhost:5000"` in my package.json. I tried replacing 'localhost' with 127.0.0.1. I tried deleting and reinstalling the package-lock.json and node_modules folders. I tried removing the proxy and using the entire url. I tried installing http proxy middleware. I tried enabling CORS on the backend too.

Either I'm cursed or doing everything wrong.

I'm using axios for handling the requests, here's the code.

```
const config = {
     headers: {
         'Content-type': "application-json"
     }
}

const body = JSON.stringify(newUser)
const res = await axios.post('/api/users', body, config)
console.log(res.data)
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a proxy issue? The error says 400 Bad Request, so apparently that's the server's response. Did you check your request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definetely not a proxy issue. The problem might be that you're passing the body as a JSON string to the axios `post()` method. No need to do that, just pass the object:

```
const res = await axios.post('/api/users', newUser, config)
```

Also, the correct value for `Content-type` is `application/json` (not `application-json`)

Comment: The request still worked with the JSON string. This whole time the problem was the dash in the Content-type header. Such a simple mistake on my part haha. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the base url to axios config :

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-type': "application-json"
    }
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
}
```

Comment: That seems to send the request to the right URL. The error now says http://localhost:5000/api/users 400 (Bad Request)
But the 400 error keeps coming up. @Ibsn mentioned to check the request and I'm sure it's formatted correctly. When I go to post route for /api/users, it looks like the request doesn't even pass through. Console logging the req object returns an empty object.

Comment: Can you try logging more info about the error ?